# Formatted printing pointer value

Tags: c, pointers, printf, language-lawyer

I found that we can print the pointer value with `%p` format specifier. N1570 `7.21.6.1(p8)`:

> **p** The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer is
>   converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an
>   implementation-defined manner

Since the pointer to void can be converted to pointer to any other object type I'm curious would the conversion by hand is necessary. Example:

```
struct test_t{
    int a;
}

void foo(){
    struct test_t *test_ptr = malloc(sizeof(*test_ptr));
    printf("Pointer test_ptr = %p\n", test_ptr);
}
```

Here I did not convert it to `void *` assuming that the compiler does this for me. Is it conforming? Or I should convert such pointers to `void *` on my own like

```
printf("Pointer test_ptr = %p\n", (void *) test_ptr);
```

The Standard specifies that the representation of and alignment of `void *` is the same as `char *`. It is not specified if the `void *` representation/alignement is must be the same as any object type.

Comment: Short answer - yes, you need the cast to void-pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version with `(void *)` is correct, and your original code causes undefined behaviour.  (You already provided the relevant Standard quote so I have no need to add further quotes).

> Since the pointer to void can be converted to pointer to any other object type I'm curious would the conversion by hand is necessary

"can be" means there is potential for a conversion to happen. Such a conversion only actually happens when it was requested , with the language standard specifying which constructs request a conversion.

For the arguments to `printf`, only the default argument promotions are applied. There are not any other conversions.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks. But since the Standard specified that `void *` and `char *` have the same representation and alignment requirements would it be possible to omit the cast in case I want to print `char *`?

Comment: @SomeName Probably

Comment: I think it can be. There is an _informative note_: **48) The  same  representation  and  alignment  requirements  are  meant  to  imply  interchangeability as arguments to functions**

Comment: @SomeName [If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9). If the rule says "The argument shall be a pointer to void", passing anything else is a violation of the requirement.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer IMO the other part about char*/void* is meant to supersede this   (this has been discussed in other LL questions)

Comment: @M.M The intent is ofc. clear. The definition of the `va_arg` semantics supports the abovementioned note in case of arguments of a variadic function. But I like UBs.